# How to resume second method after first method throws an exception C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

While looking on C# try catch tutorial, I got following question. My sample code as follows,

Inside `mainMethod()` , I need to call three separate methods. Inside `testMethodOne()`, I need to handle exception as. If `testMethodOne()` throws exception, without executing `testMethodTwo(dt)`, `mainMethod()` throwing exception. I need to call `testMethodTwo(dt);` and `testMethodThreee(dt);` if  `testMethodOne()` throws exception, how can I do it.

```
public void MainMethod(data dt){

    try{
    
    testMethodOne(dt);
    testMethodTwo(dt);
    testMethodThreee(dt);   
    
    }catch(Exception ex){
    
    
        throw ex;
    
    }
}

public void testMethodOne(dt){
    try 
    {
      //  Block of code to try
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      //  Block of code to handle errors
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question as follows (but I might be wrong, your questions is not very clear):

Even if one of your testMethods throws an exception, you still want to continue in the normal program flow with the other methods. If at least one of the method failed, `mainMethod` could then report this as [AggregateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception).

```
public void MainMethod(data dt)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    try
    {
        testMethodOne(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Add(ex);
    }

    try
    {
        testMethodTwo(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Add(ex);
    }

    try
    {
        testMethodThreee(dt);   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Add(ex);
    }

    if (exceptions.Count > 0)
    {
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you want exceptions to alter the flow of  your main method without breaking everything. One easy method is to make each 'testmethod' return a boolean.

```
public bool testMethodOne(dt){
    try 
    {
      //  Block of code to try
      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      //  Block of code to handle errors
      return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your main code you can go

```
if(!testMethodOne(dt))
    if(!testMethodTwo(dt))
        if(!testMethodThree(dt)) 
             //log that all methods failed
```

The above snippet would try each method until it finds one that succeeds. If that's not the behaviour you are looking for can you reword your question to make it clearer? If you want the opposite to happen just get rid of the ! and it will go until one fails. Alternatively you could put a throw in your catch statement in each of the testMethods, and that would stop execution once one is reached as well.